# I need help in getting an Oracle SQL Query optimized to run for a longer time period

Tags: sql, oracle

@DRapp - **Revised query below:** I need help in optimizing a Oracle/SQL query to run for more than 2 weeks of data. it works for 2 weeks of data then chokes. I inherited this. All the business rules need to stay, but is there a way I can simplify this so it will work for a larger data set? Specific examples and tips would be appreciated. This can be broken down into several queries, but needs to return the same results back. thanks for your help.
Oracle SQL Query code is as follows:

```
SELECT '1' AS group1,
    usr.USR_NAME,
    rec.USR_UID_USER,
    rec.REC_DATE_PAID,
    TO_CHAR(rec.REC_DATE_PAID, 'MM/DD/YYYY (fmDay)') AS group_date,
    rec.REC_AMOUNT,
    rec.REC_UID,
    rec.REG_UID_RECEIPT_GROUP,
    rec.REC_TAX1_AMOUNT,
    rec.REC_TAX2_AMOUNT,
    rec.REC_TAX3_AMOUNT,
    rec.REC_AMOUNT - (
    CASE
    WHEN NVL2(dis.SUMDIS, dis.SUMDIS, 0) <> 0
    THEN NVL(Fit2Sum.SumAmt, 0)
    ELSE 0
    END) - rec.REC_TAX1_AMOUNT - rec.REC_TAX2_AMOUNT - rec.REC_TAX3_AMOUNT    
    AS "GrossRevAmountnoTax",
    rec.REC_AMOUNT,
   -(
   CASE
   WHEN NVL2(dis.SUMDIS, dis.SUMDIS, 0) <> 0
   THEN NVL(Fit2Sum.SumAmt, 0)
   ELSE 0
   END)                                                                               
   AS "GrossRevAmountwTax",
   rec.REC_AMOUNT - rec.REC_TAX1_AMOUNT - rec.REC_TAX2_AMOUNT - rec.REC_TAX3_AMOUNT 
   AS "NetRevenueAmount",
   (
   CASE
   WHEN NVL(FitGrace.GraceAmount, 0) = 0
   THEN 1
   ELSE 0
  END) AS "IsGrace",
  (
  CASE
  WHEN NVL(dis.DIS_UID, 0) = 10
  THEN NVL(dis.SUMDIS, 0)
  ELSE 0
  END) AS "TicoAmount",
  (
  CASE
  WHEN NVL(dis.DIS_UID, 0) = 10
  THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END) AS "TicoCount",
  (
  CASE
  WHEN NVL(dis.DIS_UID, 0) NOT IN (10, 0)
  THEN NVL(dis.SUMDIS, 0)
  ELSE 0
  END) AS "ValidationAmount",
  (
  CASE
  WHEN NVL(dis.DIS_UID, 0) NOT IN (10, 0)
  THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END) AS "ValidationCount",
  (
  CASE
  WHEN NVL(PRFGrp.PSMCount, 0) > 1
  THEN 'Central Cashier Station'
  ELSE TO_CHAR(PRFGrp.MaxFacDescription)
  END) AS "FacilityDescription",
  (
  CASE
  WHEN NVL(PRFGrp.PSMCount, 0) > 1
  THEN 0
  ELSE MAX(PRFGrp.FAC_UID_FACILITY)
  END) AS "FacilityUID",
  dis.DIS_DESCRIPTION "DiscountDescription",
  NVL(dis.countdis, 0) "ValCount",
  NVL(dis.SUMDIS, 0) "ValAmount",
  NVL(dis.DIS_UID, 0) "DiscountUID",
  dis.VLDNUM "ValidationNumber",
  dis.THI_NAME "ValidationThirdParty",
  dis.VTE_DESCRIPTION "ValidationControlGroup",
  pmm.PMM_DESCRIPTION,
  pmm.PMM_UID,
  pmm.PAY_UID_PAYMENT_TYPE,
  psm.PSM_DESCRIPTION,
  pol.POL_DESCRIPTION,
  cas.CAS_UID,
  cas.CAS_OPEN_DATE,
  cas.CAS_CLOSE_DATE,
  MAX(fit.FIT_SALE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION)              AS SaleItem,
  NVL(per.PER_NUMBER, rtx.RTX_REPLACEMENT_NUMBER) AS TicketNumber,
  rtx.RTX_REPLACEMENT_NUMBER                      AS ReplacementNumber,
  NVL(ptx.PTX_DATE_ENTRY, ptx2.PTX_DATE_ENTRY)    AS "EntryTime",
  NVL(ptx.PTX_DATE_EXIT, ptx2.PTX_DATE_EXIT)      AS "ExitTime",
  (TO_CHAR(TRUNC(NVL(ptx.PTX_DATE_EXIT, ptx2.PTX_DATE_EXIT) - NVL(ptx.PTX_DATE_ENTRY,   
  ptx2.PTX_DATE_ENTRY)))
  || 'd '
  || TO_CHAR(mod(TRUNC((NVL(ptx.PTX_DATE_EXIT, ptx2.PTX_DATE_EXIT) - NVL(ptx.PTX_DATE_ENTRY,   
  ptx2.PTX_DATE_ENTRY)) * 24), 24))
  || 'h '
  || TO_CHAR(mod(TRUNC((NVL(ptx.PTX_DATE_EXIT, ptx2.PTX_DATE_EXIT) - NVL(ptx.PTX_DATE_ENTRY, 
  ptx2.PTX_DATE_ENTRY)) * 24 * 60), 60))
  || 'm '
  || TO_CHAR(mod(TRUNC((NVL(ptx.PTX_DATE_EXIT, ptx2.PTX_DATE_EXIT) - NVL(ptx.PTX_DATE_ENTRY, 
  ptx2.PTX_DATE_ENTRY)) * 24 * 60 * 60), 60))
  || 's')                                    AS "TimeElapsed",
  NVL(ptx.LAN_UID_ENTRY, ptx2.LAN_UID_ENTRY) AS "EntryLaneUID",
  NVL(ptx.LAN_UID_EXIT, ptx2.LAN_UID_EXIT)   AS "ExitLaneUID",
  MAX(
  (SELECT lan.LAN_DESCRIPTION
  FROM lane lan
  WHERE lan.LAN_UID = NVL(ptx.LAN_UID_ENTRY, ptx2.LAN_UID_ENTRY)
  )) AS "EntryLaneDesc",
  MAX(
  (SELECT lan.LAN_DESCRIPTION
  FROM lane lan
  WHERE lan.LAN_UID = NVL(ptx.LAN_UID_EXIT, ptx2.LAN_UID_EXIT)
  )) AS "ExitLaneDesc",
  crc.CRC_LAST_FOUR,
  ctr.CTR_CONFIRMATION_CODE,
  ctr.CTR_RETURN_CODE,
  ctr.CTR_RETURN_MESSAGE,
  ctr.CTR_TRAN_GUID,
  ctr.CTR_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_DATE,
  ctr.CTR_SUCCESS,
  ctr.CTR_TRANSACTION_DATE
  FROM RECEIPT rec
  INNER JOIN USER_ACCOUNT usr
  ON rec.USR_UID_USER = usr.USR_UID
  INNER JOIN PAYMENT_METHOD_MLKP pmm
  ON rec.PMM_UID_PAYMENT_METHOD = pmm.PMM_UID
  INNER JOIN financial_transaction fit
  ON rec.REC_UID = fit.REC_UID_RECEIPT
  LEFT JOIN permission per
  ON fit.FIT_SOURCE_OBJ_UID       = per.PER_UID
  AND fit.TAB_UID_SOURCE_OBJ_TYPE = 10
  LEFT JOIN parking_transaction ptx
  ON per.PER_UID        = ptx.PER_UID_PERMISSION
  AND ptx.PTT_UID_TYPE <> 17
  LEFT JOIN replacement_transaction rtx
  ON fit.FIT_SOURCE_OBJ_UID       = rtx.RTX_UID
  AND fit.TAB_UID_SOURCE_OBJ_TYPE = 332
  LEFT JOIN parking_transaction ptx2
  ON rtx.RTX_UID        = ptx2.RTX_UID_REPLACEMENT_TRANS
  AND ptx.PTT_UID_TYPE <> 17
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT dis.DIS_DESCRIPTION,
  dis.DIS_UID,
  vte.VTE_DESCRIPTION,
  fit2.FIT_UID              AS countdis,
  fit2.FIT_AMOUNT           AS SUMDIS,
  vld.VLD_VALIDATION_NUMBER AS VLDNUM,
  thi.THI_NAME,
  fit2.FIT_UID_PAY_ADJ_REV_ITEM
  FROM financial_transaction fit2
  INNER JOIN discount_mlkp dis
  ON fit2.DIS_UID_DISCOUNT = dis.DIS_UID
  LEFT JOIN validation vld
  ON fit2.VLD_UID_VALIDATION = vld.VLD_UID
  LEFT JOIN enc_print_history esp
  ON vld.ESP_UID_PRINT_ID = esp.ESP_UID
  LEFT JOIN third_party thi
  ON esp.THI_UID_THIRD_PARTY = thi.THI_UID
  LEFT JOIN validation_control_group vte
  ON vld.VTE_UID_VALIDATION_CTRL_GRP    = vte.VTE_UID
  WHERE fit2.DIS_UID_DISCOUNT          <> 0
  ) dis ON fit.FIT_UID_PAY_ADJ_REV_ITEM = dis.FIT_UID_PAY_ADJ_REV_ITEM
  AND rec.REC_UID                         =
  (SELECT MIN(rec2.REC_UID)
  FROM receipt rec2
  INNER JOIN receipt_group reg
  ON rec2.REG_UID_RECEIPT_GROUP   = reg.REG_UID
  WHERE rec.REG_UID_RECEIPT_GROUP = reg.REG_UID
  )
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT fit2.FIT_UID_PAY_ADJ_REV_ITEM,
  SUM(fit2.FIT_AMOUNT) AS SumAmt
  FROM financial_transaction fit2
  WHERE fit2.DIS_UID_DISCOUNT <> 0
  GROUP BY fit2.FIT_UID_PAY_ADJ_REV_ITEM
  ) Fit2Sum
  ON fit.FIT_UID_PAY_ADJ_REV_ITEM = Fit2Sum.FIT_UID_PAY_ADJ_REV_ITEM
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT fit2.FIT_UID,
  SUM(fit2.FIT_AMOUNT) AS GraceAmount
  FROM financial_transaction fit2
  GROUP BY fit2.FIT_UID
  ) FitGrace
  ON fit.FIT_UID_PAY_ADJ_REV_ITEM = FitGrace.FIT_UID
  INNER JOIN cashdrawer_session cas
  ON rec.CAS_UID_CASHDRAWER_SESSION = cas.CAS_UID
  INNER JOIN pos_station psm
  ON cas.PSM_UID_STATION = psm.PSM_UID
  INNER JOIN pos_station_type_lkp pol
  ON psm.POL_UID_STATION_TYPE = pol.POL_UID
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT pfr.PSM_UID_STATION,
  COUNT(*)                 AS PSMCount,
  MAX(fac.FAC_DESCRIPTION) AS MaxFacDescription,
  pfr.FAC_UID_FACILITY
  FROM pos_facility_rel pfr
  INNER JOIN facility fac
  ON pfr.FAC_UID_FACILITY = fac.FAC_UID
  GROUP BY pfr.PSM_UID_STATION,
  pfr.FAC_UID_FACILITY
  ) PRFGrp ON psm.PSM_UID = PRFGrp.PSM_UID_STATION
  LEFT JOIN ctr_rec_rel crr
  ON rec.REC_UID = crr.REC_UID_RECEIPT
  LEFT JOIN credit_card_transaction ctr
  ON crr.CTR_UID_CREDIT_CARD_TRANS = ctr.CTR_UID
  LEFT JOIN credit_card crc
  ON ctr.CRC_UID_PROCESSED = crc.CRC_UID
  WHERE pmm.PMM_UID       <> 12
  GROUP BY usr.USR_NAME,
  rec.USR_UID_USER,
  rec.REC_DATE_PAID,
  TO_CHAR(rec.REC_DATE_PAID, 'MM/DD/YYYY (fmDay)'),
  rec.REC_AMOUNT,
  rec.REC_UID,
  rec.REG_UID_RECEIPT_GROUP,
  rec.REC_TAX1_AMOUNT,
  rec.REC_TAX2_AMOUNT,
  rec.REC_TAX3_AMOUNT,
  dis.DIS_DESCRIPTION,
  dis.VLDNUM,
  dis.THI_NAME,
  dis.VTE_DESCRIPTION,
  pmm.PMM_DESCRIPTION,
  pmm.PMM_UID,
  pmm.PAY_UID_PAYMENT_TYPE,
  psm.PSM_DESCRIPTION,
  pol.POL_DESCRIPTION,
  cas.CAS_UID,
  cas.CAS_OPEN_DATE,
  cas.CAS_CLOSE_DATE,
  NVL(per.PER_NUMBER, rtx.RTX_REPLACEMENT_NUMBER),
  rtx.RTX_REPLACEMENT_NUMBER,
  NVL(ptx.PTX_DATE_ENTRY, ptx2.PTX_DATE_ENTRY),
  NVL(ptx.PTX_DATE_EXIT, ptx2.PTX_DATE_EXIT),
  NVL(ptx.LAN_UID_ENTRY, ptx2.LAN_UID_ENTRY),
  NVL(ptx.LAN_UID_EXIT, ptx2.LAN_UID_EXIT),
  crc.CRC_LAST_FOUR,
  ctr.CTR_CONFIRMATION_CODE,
  ctr.CTR_RETURN_CODE,
  ctr.CTR_RETURN_MESSAGE,
  ctr.CTR_TRAN_GUID,
  ctr.CTR_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_DATE,
  ctr.CTR_SUCCESS,
  ctr.CTR_TRANSACTION_DATE,
  fit.FIT_UID_PAY_ADJ_REV_ITEM,
  dis.countdis,
  dis.SUMDIS,
  dis.DIS_UID,
  psm.PSM_UID,
  (rec.REC_AMOUNT - rec.REC_TAX1_AMOUNT - rec.REC_TAX2_AMOUNT - rec.REC_TAX3_AMOUNT)
```

Comment: Congrats to inheriting this. :P There is a vast amount, and a vast amount of helpful information, on the internet about Oracle SQL query optimization. The good thing is you won't need all that. If you get the index usage right, you are at 85% to optimum performance and you usually don't need more. Google oracle sql index hints.

Comment: I personally like SQL Developer (you can get it for free) to view the execution plan of a query. It has a nice layout and you can hide and unhide parts in the tree structure of the execution plan (forget text-only representations of execution plans. way too complex). This is for analysis only. To actually do any tuning, you need to first study the execution plan and understand it. Only then you can do the tuning. This can't be done by us on this forum. It's a lot of trial and error. See here for an overview of what you will do for tuning: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_hints_tuning.htm .

Comment: I think the docs are a better source of information about optimiser hint. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/hintsref.htm#PFGRF005

Comment: Hi Daniel - when you say the Execution plan, is this the Explain Plan in SQL Developer? I am using version 3.2.20.09

Comment: Sorry I am new to Oracle, How do I access the Execution plan in Oracle 11g SQL Developer?

Comment: @AlpBerker The best way to get an execution plan is to execute `explain plan for select ...`, and then execute `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`.  It's a couple of steps more than just clicking the explain plan button in a GUI, but the text format is much more convenient for sharing and analyzing.

Answer (score 1):

If you see a step change in performance (rather than just a linear change in query duration relative to the date range), it's likely to be due to one of three issues:

1. A change in the query optimisation, which you can check with an execution plan. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_xplan.htm
2. An increase in the data volume causing a sort operation to switch from optimal to one-pass, or from one-pass to multipass, which you can check by using v$sql_workarea http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_3061.htm#REFRN30256
3. A change in the "rate" of data -- for example, if you went from 10,000 records per day to 50,000.

These would be the first issues I'd check.

Comment: Hi David, The rate of data is constant. The Query needs to run for a longer time period than 2 weeks. It should, but chokes after 2 weeks of data. Sorry I am new to Oracle, How do I access the Execution plan in Oracle 11g SQL Developer to look at your #1 Issue?

Comment: There's an example of DBMS_Xplan usage in the first link

Answer (score 1):

Aside from cleaning (format) of the query to see better what is going on, I made a few small changes.  You had a few columns that were based on select count(*) or similar based on whatever the current "fit" record was.  From the sounds of your data, that is killing the system some.  I've moved those out to three separate LEFT-JOINs to the respective tables (Fit2Sum and FitGrace linked to FIT, and PRFGrp is linked via psm alias).

Now, that said, and I dont know how large volume your tables are, you MAY want to put some limit if there are any date/time fields there that you can restrict (such as only for a month of data...).  But, by pre-querying those vs being done on every record COULD be an impact that is killing your process.

```
SELECT 
      '1' AS group1,       
      usr.USR_NAME,  
      rec.USR_UID_USER,    
      rec.REC_DATE_PAID,
      TO_CHAR(rec.rec_date_paid,'MM/DD/YYYY (fmDay)') AS group_date,  
      rec.rec_amount,
      rec.rec_uid,
      rec.reg_uid_receipt_group,
      rec.rec_tax1_amount, 
      rec.rec_tax2_amount,
      rec.rec_tax3_amount,
      MAX( rec.rec_amount - 
           - CASE WHEN NVL2( dis.sumdis, dis.sumdis,0) <> 0 
                  THEN NVL( Fit2Sum.SumAmt, 0 ) 
                  ELSE 0 END
           - rec.rec_tax1_amount
           - rec.rec_tax2_amount
           - rec.rec_tax3_amount ) AS "GrossRevAmountNoTax",
      MAX( rec.rec_amount
           - CASE WHEN NVL2(dis.sumdis,dis.sumdis,0) <> 0
                  THEN NVL( Fit2Sum.SumAmt, 0 )
                  ELSE 0 END ) AS "GrossRevAmountwTax",
      MAX( rec.REC_AMOUNT
           - rec.rec_tax1_amount
           - rec.rec_tax2_amount
           - rec.rec_tax3_amount ) AS "NetRevenueAmount",
      MAX( CASE WHEN NVL( FitGrace.GraceAmount, 0 ) = 0
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0 END) AS "IsGrace",
      /*Grace tickets have original fee amount of 0*/
      MAX( CASE WHEN NVL(dis.dis_uid,0) = 10
                THEN NVL(dis.sumdis,0)
                ELSE 0 END ) AS "TicoAmount",
      /*dis_uid = 10 is TICO*/
      MAX( CASE WHEN NVL(dis.dis_uid,0) = 10
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0 END ) AS "TicoCount",
      MAX( CASE WHEN NVL(dis.dis_uid,0) NOT IN (10,0)
                THEN NVL(dis.sumdis,0)
                ELSE 0 END ) AS "ValidationAmount",
      MAX( CASE WHEN NVL(dis.dis_uid,0) NOT IN (10,0)
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0 END ) AS "ValidationCount",
      MAX( CASE WHEN NVL( PRFGrp.PSMCount, 0 ) > 1
                THEN 'Central Cashier Station'
                ELSE TO_CHAR(PRFGrp.MaxFacDescription) END ) AS "FacilityDescription",
      /*pulls the facility description or Central Cashier Station if a central cashier station*/
      MAX( CASE WHEN NVL( PRFGrp.PSMCount, 0 ) > 1
                THEN 0
                ELSE MAX(PRFGrp.fac_uid_facility) END ) AS "FacilityUID",
      dis.dis_description "DiscountDescription",    
      NVL(dis.countdis,0) "ValCount",
      NVL(dis.sumdis,0) "ValAmount",
      NVL(dis.dis_uid,0) "DiscountUID",
      dis.VLDNUM "ValidationNumber",
      dis.thi_name "ValidationThirdParty",
      dis.vte_description "ValidationControlGroup",
      pmm.PMM_DESCRIPTION,
      pmm.pmm_uid,
      pmm.pay_uid_payment_type,
      psm.psm_description,
      pol.pol_description,
      cas.cas_uid,
      cas.cas_open_date,
      cas.cas_close_date,
      MAX(fit.fit_sale_item_description) AS SaleItem,
      NVL(per.per_number, rtx.rtx_replacement_number) AS TicketNumber,
      rtx.rtx_replacement_number AS ReplacementNumber,
      NVL(ptx.ptx_date_entry, ptx2.ptx_date_entry)    AS "EntryTime",
      NVL(ptx.ptx_date_exit, ptx2.ptx_date_exit)      AS "ExitTime",
      MAX(( TO_CHAR( TRUNC( NVL(ptx.ptx_date_exit, ptx2.ptx_date_exit)
               -NVL(ptx.ptx_date_entry, ptx2.ptx_date_entry)))||'d '||
            TO_CHAR(mod(TRUNC(( NVL(ptx.ptx_date_exit,  ptx2.ptx_date_exit)
                               -NVL(ptx.ptx_date_entry, ptx2.ptx_date_entry))*24),24))||'h '||
            TO_CHAR(mod(TRUNC(( NVL(ptx.ptx_date_exit, ptx2.ptx_date_exit)
                               -NVL(ptx.ptx_date_entry, ptx2.ptx_date_entry))*24*60),60))||'m '||
            TO_CHAR(mod(TRUNC(( NVL(ptx.ptx_date_exit,ptx2.ptx_date_exit)
                               -NVL(ptx.ptx_date_entry,ptx2.ptx_date_entry))*24*60*60),60))||'s')) AS "TimeElapsed",
      /*pulls the time between entry/exit in DD HH MM SS format*/
      NVL(ptx.lan_uid_entry, ptx2.lan_uid_entry) AS "EntryLaneUID",
      NVL(ptx.lan_uid_exit, ptx2.lan_uid_exit)   AS "ExitLaneUID",
      MAX( ( SELECT lan.lan_description
                FROM lane lan
                WHERE lan.lan_uid = NVL(ptx.lan_uid_entry, ptx2.lan_uid_entry))) AS "EntryLaneDesc",
      MAX( ( SELECT lan.lan_description
                FROM lane lan
                WHERE lan.lan_uid = NVL(ptx.lan_uid_exit, ptx2.lan_uid_exit))) AS "ExitLaneDesc",
      crc.crc_last_four,
      ctr.ctr_confirmation_code,
      ctr.ctr_return_code,
      ctr.ctr_return_message,
      ctr.ctr_tran_guid,
      ctr.ctr_authorization_request_date,
      ctr.ctr_success,
      ctr.ctr_transaction_date
   FROM 
      RECEIPT rec
         INNER JOIN USER_ACCOUNT usr
            ON rec.USR_UID_USER = usr.USR_UID

         INNER JOIN PAYMENT_METHOD_MLKP pmm     
            ON rec.PMM_UID_PAYMENT_METHOD = pmm.PMM_UID

         INNER JOIN financial_transaction fit   
            ON rec.rec_uid =  fit.rec_uid_receipt

            LEFT JOIN permission per
               ON fit.fit_source_obj_uid = per.per_uid
               AND fit.tab_uid_source_obj_type = 10

               LEFT JOIN parking_transaction ptx
                  ON per.per_uid = ptx.per_uid_permission
                  AND ptx.ptt_uid_type <> 17

            LEFT JOIN replacement_transaction rtx  
               ON fit.fit_source_obj_uid = rtx.rtx_uid
               AND fit.tab_uid_source_obj_type = 332

               LEFT JOIN parking_transaction ptx2
                  ON rtx.rtx_uid = ptx2.rtx_uid_replacement_trans
                  AND ptx.ptt_uid_type <> 17

            LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
                              dis.dis_description,
                              dis.dis_uid,
                              vte.vte_description,
                              fit2.fit_uid AS countdis,
                              fit2.fit_amount AS SUMDIS,
                              vld.vld_validation_number AS "VLDNUM",
                              thi.thi_name,
                              fit2.fit_uid_pay_adj_rev_item
                           FROM 
                              financial_transaction fit2
                                 INNER JOIN discount_mlkp dis
                                    ON fit2.dis_uid_discount = dis.dis_uid
                                 LEFT JOIN validation vld
                                    ON fit2.vld_uid_validation = vld.vld_uid
                                    LEFT JOIN enc_print_history esp
                                       ON vld.esp_uid_print_id = esp.esp_uid
                                       LEFT JOIN third_party thi
                                          ON esp.thi_uid_third_party = thi.thi_uid
                                    LEFT JOIN validation_control_group vte 
                                       ON vld.vte_uid_validation_ctrl_grp = vte.vte_uid
                           WHERE 
                              fit2.dis_uid_discount <> 0) dis
               ON fit.fit_uid_pay_adj_rev_item = dis.fit_uid_pay_adj_rev_item
               AND rec.rec_uid = ( SELECT MIN(rec2.rec_uid)
                                     FROM receipt rec2
                                        INNER JOIN receipt_group reg 
                                           ON rec2.reg_uid_receipt_group = reg.reg_uid
                                     WHERE rec.reg_uid_receipt_group = reg.reg_uid)
/*
this is grabbing the detail of any validations used during the transaction.  If more then one    
validation is used per transient, it will pull the transient permit record multiple times   
(equal to the number of validations used).  This is by design so we can get the detail info,  
must account for these potential duplicates within report using running totals- Added logic to  
account for split payments, case statement forces the validation info to only show for the 
first receipt of the receipt group- JB21213
*/

            LEFT JOIN ( select
                              fit2.fit_uid_pay_adj_rev_item,
                              SUM( fit2.fit_amount ) as SumAmt
                           from
                              financial_transaction fit2
                           where
                              fit2.dis_uid_discount <> 0
                           group by 
                              fit2.fit_uid_pay_adj_rev_item ) Fit2Sum
               ON fit.fit_uid_pay_adj_rev_item = Fit2Sum.fit_uid_pay_adj_rev_item

            LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
                              fit2.fit_uid,
                              SUM(fit2.fit_amount) as GraceAmount
                           FROM 
                              financial_transaction fit2
                           GROUP BY
                              fit2.fit_uid ) FitGrace
               ON fit.fit_uid_pay_adj_rev_item = FitGrace.fit_uid

         INNER JOIN cashdrawer_session cas
            ON rec.cas_uid_cashdrawer_session = cas.cas_uid
            INNER JOIN pos_station psm
               ON cas.psm_uid_station = psm.psm_uid
               INNER JOIN pos_station_type_lkp pol
                  ON psm.pol_uid_station_type = pol.pol_uid
               LEFT JOIN ( select
                                 prf.psm_uid_station,
                                 COUNT(*) as PSMCount,
                                 MAX(fac.fac_description) as MaxFacDescription
                              from
                                 pos_facility_rel pfr
                                    INNER JOIN facility fac 
                                       ON pfr.fac_uid_facility = fac.fac_uid
                              group by
                                 prf.psm_uid_station ) PRFGrp
                  ON psm.psm_uid = PRFGrp.psm_uid_station

         LEFT JOIN ctr_rec_rel crr
            ON rec.rec_uid = crr.rec_uid_receipt
            LEFT JOIN credit_card_transaction ctr  
               ON crr.ctr_uid_credit_card_trans = ctr.ctr_uid
               LEFT JOIN credit_card crc
                  ON ctr.crc_uid_processed = crc.crc_uid

   WHERE 
      pmm.pmm_uid <> 12
   GROUP BY 
      usr.USR_NAME,
      rec.USR_UID_USER,
      rec.REC_DATE_PAID,
      rec.REC_AMOUNT,
      rec.rec_tax1_amount,
      rec.rec_tax2_amount,
      rec.rec_tax3_amount,
      pmm.PMM_DESCRIPTION,
      rec.rec_uid,
      rec.reg_uid_receipt_group,
      psm.psm_description,
      cas.cas_uid,
      cas.cas_open_date,
      cas.cas_close_date,
      fit.fit_uid_pay_adj_rev_item,
      dis.dis_description,
      dis.countdis,
      dis.sumdis,
      dis.VLDNUM,
      dis.dis_uid,
      dis.thi_name,
      dis.vte_description,
      pmm.pay_uid_payment_type,
      psm.psm_uid,
      pol.pol_description,
      pmm.pmm_uid,
      TO_CHAR(rec.rec_date_paid,'MM/DD/YYYY (fmDay)'),
      NVL(per.per_number,rtx.rtx_replacement_number),
      rtx.rtx_replacement_number,
      NVL(ptx.ptx_date_entry,ptx2.ptx_date_entry),
      NVL(ptx.ptx_date_exit,ptx2.ptx_date_exit),
      NVL(ptx.lan_uid_entry,ptx2.lan_uid_entry),
      NVL(ptx.lan_uid_exit,ptx2.lan_uid_exit),
      crc.crc_last_four,
      ctr.ctr_confirmation_code,
      ctr.ctr_return_code,
      ctr.ctr_return_message,
      ctr.ctr_tran_guid,
      ctr.ctr_authorization_request_date,
      ctr.ctr_success,
      ctr.ctr_transaction_date,
      (rec.rec_amount 
         - rec.rec_tax1_amount 
         - rec.rec_tax2_amount 
         - rec.rec_tax3_amount );
```

**QUERY CLARIFICATION...**

To help understand what is going on with the revised query.  On several of the fields, you were running the same query multiple times getting a COUNT(*) based on whatever was the "current" ID, being some facility, person, whatever.  If you do that query at the field level, it runs those queries EACH TIME per column, per row...

What I have done was to do a SINGLE pre-aggregation on each respective per facility, person, whatever for those other aliases (such as Fit2Sum, FitGrace, PRFGrp).  While keeping the respective "ID" as the group by column in those result sets, the LEFT-JOIN points to one record in each respective set based on that JOIN criteria.

Now, the case/when construct.  Since the pre-aggregations have already been performed, and the join is per the respective "ID" column, you no longer need the COUNT(*) for each column, just grab the final column name from the pre-aggregation query and test that.  If the record is found and has a count, do the same as your original COUNT(*).  In some case, it would return an ID, others, return 0.  So, for your example of "GrossRevAmountnoTax",

```
 rec.rec_amount-(CASE WHEN NVL2(dis.sumdis,dis.sumdis,0) <> 0
                   THEN
                      (SELECT SUM(fit2.fit_amount)
                         FROM financial_transaction fit2
                        WHERE fit.fit_uid_pay_adj_rev_item = fit2.fit_uid_pay_adj_rev_item
                          AND fit2.dis_uid_discount <> 0)
                   ELSE 0
              END)-rec.rec_tax1_amount-rec.rec_tax2_amount-rec.rec_tax3_amount      
  AS "GrossRevAmountnoTax",
```

you are selecting the sum() of the fit_amount based on the fit_uid_pay_adj_rev_item.  Since I prequeried this into the Fit2Sum alias, the join is on the fit_uid_pay_adj_rev_item and am just grabbing that column (Fit2Sum.SumAmt) so the query does NOT have to be done repeatedly.

```
 rec.rec_amount - 
         - CASE WHEN NVL2( dis.sumdis, dis.sumdis,0) <> 0 
                THEN NVL( Fit2Sum.SumAmt, 0 ) 
                ELSE 0 END
         - rec.rec_tax1_amount
         - rec.rec_tax2_amount
         - rec.rec_tax3_amount AS "GrossRevAmountnoTax",
```

Again, since it is already sitting at the record in Fit2Sum alias, it can immediately follow with

```
 rec.rec_amount-(CASE WHEN NVL2(dis.sumdis,dis.sumdis,0) <> 0
                   THEN
                      (SELECT SUM(fit2.fit_amount)
                         FROM financial_transaction fit2
                        WHERE fit.fit_uid_pay_adj_rev_item = fit2.fit_uid_pay_adj_rev_item
                          AND fit2.dis_uid_discount <> 0)
                   ELSE 0
              END) AS "GrossRevAmountwTax",
```

without having to requery the set yet again.

So, your issue with the PRFGrp.PSMCount is doing a similar thing.  The alias PRFGrp was based on another table, column/condition and summation.  The join has that available and SHOULD be visible to your query, not the "fit" alias as I originally had.  So, please look at the alias references and final column names in case I missed something and hopefully this clarification makes more sense to you.

**ADDITIONAL REVISIONS**

The fields that have case/when that are not part of the group by expression are probably causing the failure as you should group by any and all non-aggregate columns in the returned set.

These include GrossRevAmountNoTax, NetRevenueAmount, and others... So, I just changed them to MAX() respectively.  Since the group by all those other criteria including the low level ID columns would imply you don't get duplicates, so applying a MAX() to such should be the same value

Comment: Hi DRapp, thanks this helps a lot. I plan on querying this by a date range for a month. Your changes I think will really help but I am getting a small error with an invalid identifier : ORA-00904: "FAC"."FAC_UID" invalid identifier:                                                        Here is the statement:                                          CASE WHEN NVL( PRFGrp.PSMCount, 0 ) > 1
           THEN 0
           ELSE MAX(fac.fac_uid) END AS "FacilityUID",                                                   can you help me resolve this? It might work. I can do generate a explain plan then.

Comment: @user3119726, it apparently cant find the column "fac.fac_uid" which may be a column type-o or alias incorrect..

Comment: I agree, a bit puzzled though. the alias is defined further down as code: INNER JOIN facility fac                                        ON pfr.fac_uid_facility = fac.fac_uid   the main table is Facility and the column is fac_uid, so I think the table name referenced is ok, is something out of order as far as declarations? thanks. Alp

Comment: @user3119726, found it... For "FacilityUID", changed from fac.fac_uid to PRFGrp.fac_uid_facility... I updated query above

Comment: Hi @DRapp I am still getting the same error. I can help if I understand what is going on in the case statement part CASE WHEN NVL( PRFGrp.PSMCount, 0 ) > 1
           THEN 0
           ELSE MAX(PRFGrp.fac_uid_facility) END AS "FacilityUID",
do we need max()? also what is this doing exactly? Thanks for your help, I really appreciate your time. I think we are close once we get the field straightened out.

Comment: @user3119726, revised answer with query clarification below original posted query.

Comment: Thanks @DRapp I will look over it and track the files down that is causing the error. Hopefully everything else is right.

Comment: Hi @DRapp Found the problem, replaced fac.fac_uid with PRFGrp.FAC_UID_FACILITY. code:   CASE
    WHEN NVL(PRFGrp.PSMCount, 0) > 1
    THEN 0
    ELSE MAX(PRFGrp.FAC_UID_FACILITY)
  END) AS "FacilityUID",  but now I am getting an error with code: CASE
    WHEN NVL(PRFGrp.PSMCount, 0) > 1
    THEN 'Central Cashier Station'
    ELSE TO_CHAR(MAX(FAC.FAC_DESCRIPTION))
  END) AS "FacilityDescription",    on the fac.fac_description field where it was running before, getting the same error now on this field :)

Comment: @AlpBerker, revised.  I adjusted the PRFGrp query to get the max( fac...) field there so it is available with the PRFGrp alias, so that case/when is now using the PRGGrp field.  Should get you going.

Comment: Hi @DRapp I made the changes. Almost there, I am getting a grouping error as follows on ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 15 Column: 14     Since it is a summation field, it is having a problem with grouping on the fit2sum.SumAmount at code: CASE
    WHEN NVL2(dis.SUMDIS, dis.SUMDIS, 0) <> 0
    THEN NVL(Fit2Sum.SumAmount, 0)
    ELSE 0 Should this just be revised for just the field instead of the AS? Please see the revised code on the very top with  changes, sorry the editing is bad, again thanks for your help.

Comment: @AlpBerker, make a change... in the subquery for Fit2Sum alias, I had the column name as "SumAmount", but in the query portion it was referencing column "SumAmt"... change the subquery result column name as "SumAmt" to make them match.

Comment: Hi @DRapp I changed like you said for CASE
    WHEN NVL2(dis.SUMDIS, dis.SUMDIS, 0) <> 0
    THEN NVL(Fit2Sum.SumAmt, 0)
    ELSE 0
  END)    and  CASE
    WHEN NVL2(dis.SUMDIS, dis.SUMDIS, 0) <> 0
    THEN NVL(Fit2Sum.SumAmt, 0)
    ELSE 0
  END)       I tried just SumAmt without Fit2Sum also but I am still getting the grouping error. I think the subquery on the bottom needs another grouping field perhaps?  See top for changes. Thanks - Alp

Comment: Hi @DRapp - puzzled here. I tried some more items but I am still getting the grouping error. The grouping fields look right but I am getting the error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 15 Column: 14   The code on that line is: THEN NVL(Fit2Sum.SumAmt, 0)    help would be appreciated.

Comment: @AlpBerker, revised again, changed some fields to MAX() where not a part of the group by, which should be no impact based on all the other columns causing uniqueness to the computed columns.  I re-pasted the ENTIRE query.  Run that, see where we are.

Comment: Hi @DRapp, I see what you did with the MAX(), I got a parenthesis error at  ELSE 0 END AS "GrossRevAmountwTax" error is: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 23 Column: 30    I realize putting a right parenthesis after the END would take care of this, but the entire statement has a problem when I do this. Not sure what direction to take on this. Again, thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: @AlpBerker, sorry, due to the multiple case/when and not having tables to run, I would otherwise have had it earlier.  I missed a close paren after the END ) AS "GrossRevAmountwTax"... Put one in there.  And had DOUBLE close paren at the )) AS "IsGrace", remove one of those.

Comment: Hi @DRapp , I fully understand this isn't easy without tables that did work though I am hitting another issue further down at line - rec.rec_tax3_amount ) AS "NetRevenueAmount",    error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:      I think it is an issue with the , or something  but I want to run it pass you.
*Action:
Error at Line: 27 Column: 44

Comment: @AlpBerker, go to bottom area of the screen... 4th link under the bar is "chat". Then go to the room "OracleTollQuery"  I'll be in there so we don't drag this on too much in comment section and get it resolved.

Comment: Hi @Drapp I don't have enough reputation points to use the chat feature. Sorry, any other suggestions?

Comment: "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here" is the message I got. I saw your posting about the minus sign, made the change.